# How to make text appear when hovering over an image that's inside an anchor tag and the anchor tag is inside a div?

Tags: html, image, tags, hover, anchor

i really need help on this. I looked everywhere in the web and i tried so many different things and nothing worked for me. I'm kind of new in programming and maybe this is a newbie question but please help me. I'm trying to make some text appear below one image whenever i pass the mouse over the image.
I managed to do it with some simple code that i found on the web like this:

CSS

```
.show {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

a:hover + .show {display: block;}
```

HTML

```
<a><img src="../auxiliar/miniatura-2-inactivo.jpg" width="331"      height="331" onmouseover="this.src='../auxiliar/miniatura-2.jpg'" width="331" height="331" onmouseout="this.src='../auxiliar/miniatura-2-inactivo.jpg'" /></a> 

<div class="show">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

So, this does the trick but, for my specific case i need the anchor tag to be inside of a div, and as soon as i put the anchor tag inside a div tag it just stops showing the text when i hover the image. Of course I did the changes in CSS like this:

CSS

```
.show {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

    div a:hover + .show {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<a ><img src="../auxiliar/miniatura-2-inactivo.jpg" width="331" height="331"  onmouseover="this.src='../auxiliar/miniatura-2.jpg'" width="331" height="331" onmouseout="this.src='../auxiliar/miniatura-2-inactivo.jpg'" /></a>
</div> 

<div class="show">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

I even tried to add id's and classes to the anchor tag and the div tag to try to reach where i need but i failed. I need your help, what can i do? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

```
$('#image').hover(function() {
        $('#text').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#text').hide();
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y532ouzj/2/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Shaggy, for the answer, but even though it works on fiddle I can't make it to work on the html file and I linked all right to the src, i think. Another problem is that, I need the text to appear only when i hover over the image and not the whole div. I'll explain the whole element so i can make my self clear. There's a <div> that inside has an <ul> and inside the <li> tags are the <a> tags with the images. What i need is to have some text shown every time i hover one of those images. Thanks again

Comment: In fact i just made it :) I just had to add - $(function () { - in the beginnig of the script you did! Thanks a lot!